Automatically computing width of lstlisting inside wrapfig environment
I have many lstlistings inside wrapfigure environments like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,listings,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{I}{0.85in}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=,frame=single]
class C1
0 +---
0 | v0: C0
0 +---
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

I set all of the widths manually right now until they look about right.
Is there a way to create a command or environment that will do this for me?  I tried to adapt this similar question for images but it didn't work right.  I'm guessing that is because lstlisting is an environment.
Ideally, I'd like to write
\begin{autowrapfigure}{I}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=,frame=single]
class C1
0 +---
0 | v0: C0
0 +---
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{autowrapfigure}

and have it automatically figure out the correct width to pass to the wrapfigure environment.

If you specify a width of 0pt, wrapfigure should compute the width for you.

Thanks, I did not know that.  It does have the same problem with frames as my answer though.

It seems that frame=single expands and overlays the page.  You can add the frame separately using \fbox around a savebox (without the overlay).  Not sure what causes the extra blank line at the top.  You can remove it with \raisebox{\baselineskip}[\ht0]{\usebox0}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,listings,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
\begin{lrbox}{0}%
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=]
class C1
0 +---
0 | v0: C0
0 +---
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}%
    \fbox{\usebox0}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


Both lrbox and wrapfigure are fragile (in opposite ways) w.r.t \begin and \end.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,listings,lipsum}

\newcommand{\wraparg}{}% reserve global name

\newenvironment{autowrap}[1]{% #1=l, r, etc.
  \xdef\wraparg{#1}% save argument
  \begin{lrbox}{0}}% text goes here
 {\end{lrbox}%
  \wrapfigure{\wraparg}{0pt}% \fragile
    \fbox{\usebox0}
  \endwrapfigure}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{autowrap}{l}%
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=]
class C1
0 +---
0 | v0: C0
0 +---
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{autowrap}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


I was hoping for a command or environment to apply automatically, but I ended up just applying this by hand to all my listings, so marking this as the answer.

I was able to find a partial solution.  As you can see, the width is computed correctly, but the frame does not seem to respect the width.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,listings,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\wrapboxcontent}

\newenvironment{autowrapfigure}[1][r]
{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\wrapboxcontent}
}{%
  \end{lrbox}
  \wrapfigure{I}{\wd\wrapboxcontent}
    \usebox{\wrapboxcontent}
  \endwrapfigure
}

\begin{autowrapfigure}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=,frame=single]
class C1
0 +---
0 | v0: C0
0 +---
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{autowrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


